# How to use SpringBoot PropertySource to read from an external configuration file

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration-files

I've created a configuration class that will store configuration values.  These configuration values should be read in from a configuration file "`config.properties`". Below is the config class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.boot.Training.*"})
@PropertySource("file:/src/main/java/config.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${myFirstName}")
    private static String myFirstName;

    @Value("${myLastName}")
    private static String myLastName;

    public static void showVariables() {
        System.out.println("firstName: " + myFirstName);
        System.out.println("lastName: " + myLastName);
    }

}
```

And below are the contents of the `config.properties` file:

```
myFirstName=John    
myLastName=Doe
```

Running my program should simply print the values of these variables. But instead, Eclipse tells me it cannot find the `config.properties` file, even though I specified that it is located in `/src/main/java/config.properties` .

I'm likely specifying the file location without taking something else into account.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location you are using (`file:/src/main/java/config.properties`) refers to an absolute path rather than one relative to your project home.

A more common way to do this is to ship `config.properties` as part of your project in a resources directory, and refer to it via the classpath. If you move it to `/src/main/resources/config.properties`, you can load it this way:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
```

I believe in theory you could just leave it in `/src/main/java` and change your `@PropertySource` location to what I have above, but moving it to `/resources` is the more idiomatic way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The basic way to specify a `file:` location to appoint a properties file that is located elsewhere on your host environment is:

```
@PropertySource("file:/path/to/application.properties")
```

- Note that `/path/to/application.properties` should be absolute path pointing to your `.properties` file (in your example you are mixing `file:` usage and **relative path** which is not correct )

it is also possible to specify a **system property** or an **environment variable** that will be resolved to its actual value when your application starts. For example, ${CONF_DIR} below will be replaced with its associated value when the Spring application starts:

1. Open /etc/environment in any text editor like nano or gedit and add the following line:

   ```
   CONF_DIR=/path/to/directory/with/app/config/files
   ```
2. Check it system variable has been set:

   ```
   echo $CONF_DIR
   /path/to/directory/with/app/config/files
   ```
3. use PropertySource like:

   ```
   @PropertySource("file:${CONF_DIR}/application.properties")
   ```